# Custom WP_Query with complex 'post_status' argument

Tags: posts, wp-query

I'm trying to run a `WP_Query()` with a bit of a twist.

I need to include two `post_status`es and specifically exclude another.

I've got `WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'customstatus' ) ) );` which works, but it seems to also pull in `auto-draft`, which I can NOT have.

Is there a way to do like

`'post_status' => array( array('publish', 'customstatus'), 'not_in' => 'auto-draft' ))`

where I can include two and exclude one explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Things to note:

#### It depends on what type of page the query is happening

If you're logged in, `private` post status will be drawn in for example.

#### Use a filter

As the status is something that gets added to the `WHERE` clause, you have a pretty specific filter that you can use to alter the actual query string.

```
apply_filters_ref_array('posts_where', array( $where, &$this ) );
```

So an actual callback would look close to this general example:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse82200_posts_where_status' );
function wpse82200_posts_where_status( $where, $query )
{
    // Run only once; Don't intercept later queries
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Do your replace logic here

    return $where;
}
```

Of course, you should add that filter callback right before the line where you do the query, so nothing gets in between. The example removes itself after firing once.